# how to launch a coroutine inside a composable in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a LazyColumn that is getting the items from the viewModel and every thing is working perfectly, But **What I want is when a new Item is inserted to the lazy column I want the the background color of the new Item to be green for 2 seconds and then it turns back to white** .
And here is what I did to achieve that but the Item keeps being green:

```
@Composable
fun SingleItem(item: Item) {
val new = remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
val color: MutableState<Color> = remember {
    if (new.value)
        mutableStateOf(Color(0xFFB9F6CA))
    else
        mutableStateOf(Color(0xFFFDFDFD))
}
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(4.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    backgroundColor = color.value
) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        new.value= !new.value
    }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(text = item.name, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
        Text(text = "${item.quantity}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
    }
}
```

[Here is a Screen shot of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ2zn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression,

```
val color: MutableState<Color> = remember {
    if (new.value)
        mutableStateOf(Color(0xFFB9F6CA))
    else
        mutableStateOf(Color(0xFFFDFDFD))
}
```

should just be,

```
val color = if (new.value) Color(0xFFB9F6CA) else Color(0xFFDFDFD)
```

The lambda to `remember` is only ever called once for the composition and is not considered invalid when `new` changes. There is no need to `remember` a `Color()` value as it is fast enough that repeating it whenever `new.value` is changes is not going to be a significant burden for composition.

Also, as Gabriele Mariotti suggested, use the composition scope instead of `Global`. In this case, it doesn't matter much as it just potentially keeps the reference to `new` alive for 2 seconds longer than needed but it is a very good habit to get into as, when you use the composition context the coroutine is cancelled automatically when the composition is no longer needed (such as the row scrolling off screen).

Also, if the color is not just a placeholder for seeing the effect of a coroutine, consider using animations for this as you would probably want the color to transition instead of snap.

Comment: every thing is working fine now and thanks for the animation Tip

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [**`rememberCoroutineScope`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remembercoroutinescope) function that returns a `CoroutineScope`.
Something like:

```
// Create a CoroutineScope that follows this composable's lifecycle
val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

composableScope.launch {
    //... your code
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/kotlin#coroutines).

Comment: Now it give some warning:
"Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition"

Comment: @brucemax you have to run it on any non compose function like onClick

Comment: This requires `LaunchedEffect`